# using jacobi method to solve laplace equation PYTHON

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python and am trying to recreate the electric potential in a metal box using the laplace equation and the jacobi method. I have written a code that seems to work initially, however I am getting the error: IndexError: index 8 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7 and can not figure out why. any help would be awesome!

```
from visual import*
from visual.graph import*
import numpy as np

 lenx = leny = 7
delta = 2

vtop = [-1,-.67,-.33,.00,.33,.67,1]
vbottom = [-1,-.67,-.33,.00,.33,.67,1]
vleft = -1
vright = 1

vguess= 0

x,y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,lenx), np.arange(0,leny))

v = np.empty((lenx,leny))
v.fill(vguess)

v[(leny-1):,:] = vtop
v [:1,:] = vbottom
v[:,(lenx-1):] = vright
v[:,:1] = vleft

maxit = 500

for iteration in range (0,maxit):
    for i in range(1,lenx):
        for j in range(1,leny-1):
            v[i,j] = .25*(v[i+i][j] + v[i-1][j] + v[i][j+1] + v[i][j-1])
            print v
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
This includes code we can paste & run to reproduce the problem, and the full error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from a quick glance at your code it seems as though the indexing error is happening at this part and can be changed accordingly:

```
# you had v[i+i][j] instead if v[i+1][j]
v[i,j] = .25*(v[i+1][j] + v[i-1][j] + v[i][j+1] + v[i][j-1])
```

You simply added and extra `i` to your indexing which would have definitely been out of range

Comment: My pleasure.  Good luck with this code! I'm currently taking an electrostatics class at my university and this kind of coding is very applicable!